# Removing react JSX dependency from browser.js

Tags: reactjs

I am building a progressive web app with react.  I have chosen to write using JSX.

Given that I am using JSX, then I have to import `browser.js`.
Now this `browser.js` is a 2 MB file which transforms this JSX code to plain JavaScript code. The size of the file means that my app takes a lot of time to load initially.

I want to know what are my alternatives:

1. Should I use react without JSX so that I do not have any dependency on `browser.js`.
2. Is there any alternative to `browser.js` which is less than 200kb in size?

I am still not clear whether if I use react without JSX then my dependency on `browser.js` can be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack is an alternative. You can use Babel to transpile your code with it. Here's an example `webpack.config.js` file.

```
module.exports = {

 // This code will be compiled 
 entry: "./app/App.js",

 // Then output into this file
 output: {
    filename: "public/bundle.js"
 },


 // This will be what we do
  module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            excluse: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
                // These are the specific transformations we'll be using. 
                presets: ['react', 'es2015']
            }
         }
     ]
  }
}
```

http://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation

There are several npm packages to install. Here's an example `package.json` file.

```
 {
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "public/index.html",
  "scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
 },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.12.0",
    "history": "^1.13.1",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "react-router": "^1.0.1" //for routing 
 },
 "devDependencies": {
   "babel-core": "^6.3.13",
   "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
   "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
   "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
   "webpack": "^1.13.1"
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

‍♀️ **Alternatives to JSX**

There are some alternatives to JSX that do not require any transpilers:

1. [React on Lambda (1.2KB gzip)](https://github.com/sultan99/react-on-lambda)
2. [React hyperscript (1.1KB gzip)](https://github.com/mlmorg/react-hyperscript)
3. [FP Dom](https://github.com/fp-dom/fp-dom)